# Can Multiprocessor Systems Implement Both Temporal Multithreading and Simultaneous Multithreading?

Tags: concurrency, parallel-computing, threads, multi-tasking

I am aware that multiprocessor systems often implement simultaneous multithreading in order to allow multiple threads to run on different CPUs. I am also aware that uni-core systems often implement temporal multithreading (fine-grained/preemptive or coarse-grained/cooperative) to allow for a more efficient use of the CPU through the use of context switches.

However, I am curious **whether it is possible (or logical) to have a simultaneously multithreaded system also allow for the time-sharing between threads on each CPU**, which is prevalent in temporal multithreading systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  You can simultaneously run multiple threads on different CPUs in parallel; and also a single CPU can context switch between threads (i.e., both what you are calling simultaneous multithreading + temporal multithreading).   Nothing prevents it.